# Show title bar on hover in VB6

Tags: vb6

How can I show the title bar of a form only if the mouse is at the top of the form like on Windows Media Player 9? I already implemented this but it is awkward and the controls/elements and the window moves down a little if I use my code while WMP 9/10's window stays at the current position.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim pos as coord  'my type, has x as long and y as long
    GetCursorPos pos
    If pos.y * 15 > Me.Top - 500 And pos.y * 15 < Me.Top + 300 And pos.x * 15 > Me.Left And pos.x * 15 < Me.Left + Me.Width Then
        Me.BorderStyle = 2
        Me.Caption = Me.Caption
    Else
        Me.BorderStyle = 0
        Me.Caption = Me.Caption
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the form top property by the height of the title bar so the rest of the form and contents stay "in position"?

Comment: Don't modify `BorderStyle` property as this introduces flicker and repositioning. Leave the title bar and border as they are but use `SetWindowRgn` to cut them out (make them invisible).

Comment: I tried SetWindowRgn, it is better but if I capture the window by Alt+PrtSc, I can see the content at the back of WMP9 but my app's screenshot shows the title bar and the magenta background(that I made invisible) in paint. What is the exact way that WMP 9 used?

Comment: You can check if WMP's top window has the `WS_EX_LAYERED (&H80000)` style set which allows per-pixel transparency by setting an alpha mask for the hwnd which is much more powerful technique than old-school clip regions.